# Validity of residue outside the domain

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

[image]

Using the identity theorem I can see that $f(z)=\dfrac{2}{3+z}$ and hence 1 is true and 4 is false. This far is easy. But for 2 and 3 I can see that $f$ is not defined at $z=3$ and $-3$ is not a isolated singular point of $f$ considering the domain $D.$ Is this a valid logic to strike out 2 and 3?

Comment: I'd say 2. and 3. can be discarded since $3 \not \in \mathbb{D}$ and $-3 \not \in \mathbb{D}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing here the point that you *already* answered correctly, imo, the question: you chose (1) and that's fine, period.

Now, you don't have to worry what happens outside $\,\Bbb D\,$ as your question's function has existence **only** in $\,\Bbb D\,$ ...

BTW, your $\,f\,$ *also* fulfills (3)...